# Netplan not detecting MII uplink down on a bonded network interface

Tags: netplan, network-bonding

Dealing with a weired issue where netplan is not detecting the uplink going down for one of it's primary slave and not selecting the other slave. I also tried setting up all parameters of mii-monitor-interval but that doesn't seems to be working either.

```
root@core2:~# lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
root@core2:~# uname -a
Linux core2 4.15.0-121-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 16:16:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@core2:~# dpkg -l | grep netplan
ii netplan.io0.98-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 YAML network configuration abstraction for various backends
root@core2:~#
Config file ->
  network:  
    version: 2   
    renderer: networkd   
    ethernets:   
      enp6s0f0:   
         dhcp4: no   
       enp6s0f1:
        dhcp4: no    
    
    bonds:
      bond0:
        addresses:   
        - 10.10.10.250/24
    
        gateway4: 10.10.10.1
    
        nameservers:    
          addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      interfaces:    
      - enp6s0f0    
      - enp6s0f1
    
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup    
        primary: enp6s0f0
        mii-monitor-interval: 10s    
        min-links: 1
        down-delay: 50
```

Interesting issue is that event after setting mii-monitor-interval value to 10s, it's not updating on bond interface. It's shows 0ms and that means netplan is not monitoring the mii uplink.

```
root@core2:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: enp6s0f0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: enp6s0f0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Slave Interface: enp6s0f1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:3e:3f:29
Slave queue ID: 0
Slave Interface: enp6s0f0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:3e:3f:28
Slave queue ID: 0
root@core2:~#
```

Comment: Does your .yaml file actually look like what you posted... with everything starting in column #1, or do you have some indentation?

Comment: Yes, it has indentation. It's just the way I posted here on the forum.

Comment: To be clear, 'netplan' does not monitor anything.  But the /proc/net/bonding/bond0 contents do show that the monitoring value is not set, which means the kernel is not monitoring.  Can you check that `MIIMonitorSec=` has been properly set under `/run/systemd/network`?

Comment: Yes, it was there. But still didn't work. We end up using ifenslave

Answer (score 1):

Long time after the question was asked, but I ran into a similar problem.

Changing the value in netplan's config and doing a netplan apply did not change the existing mii-monitor-interval, leaving it at 0 (and thus off)

A reboot would make it live. As would deleting the bond device (ip link delete interfacename) then a netplan apply.

Netplan isn't good for changes this way. If the bond exists, it won't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 3

I had the same problem with ubuntu 20.04.

I could change the primary device of the bond but if I disconnect the nic's cable no failover routing happens.

MIIMonitorSec is properly set up in /run/systemd/network

Ah, after a full reboot and carefully restarting a ping probe it started to work.

Here is my configuration:

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
        eno2:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces: [eno2, eno1]
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: eno1
        mii-monitor-interval: 200
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bond0]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
```

test case1:

> i.  ping foo.bar ii. (remove cable from primary bonding nic)
>
> ping get stucks
>
> iii. CTRL-C (abort ping)
>
> iv. ping foo.bar # restart ping probe

Expect:

```
ping foo.bar
0.2 ms success
(..)
NIC Copper is down
package loss

ping foo.bar
0.2 ms success
```